# how to read xml file from url using php

Tags: php, xml, url

I have to read an XML file from an URL

```
$map_url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=".$merchant_address_url."&destination=".$customer_address_url."&sensor=false";
```

This gives me an URL like:

> http://maps.google.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=Quentin+Road+Brooklyn%2C+New+York%2C+11234+United+States&destination=550+Madison+Avenue+New+York%2C+New+York%2C+10001+United+States&sensor=false

I am using this function to read and then get data:

```
 $response_xml_data = file_get_contents($map_url);
 if($response_xml_data){
     echo "read";
 }

 $data = simplexml_load_string($response_xml_data);
 echo "<pre>"; print_r($data); exit;
```

But no luck, any help?

Answer (score 35):

you can get the data from the XML by using "simplexml_load_file" Function. Please refer this link

http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php

```
$url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=Quentin+Road+Brooklyn%2C+New+York%2C+11234+United+States&destination=550+Madison+Avenue+New+York%2C+New+York%2C+10001+United+States&sensor=false";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
print_r($xml);
```

Comment: yes i tried simplexml_load_file but when i print_r then it gives me blank page

Comment: Make sure you have allow_url_fopen turned on in your php.ini

Answer (score 14):

Your code seems right, check if you have [fopen wrappers](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) enabled (`allow_url_fopen = On` on php.ini)

Also, as mentioned by other answers, you should provide a properly encoded URI or encode it using [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function. You should also check if there is any error fetching the XML string and if there is any parsing error, which you can output using [libxml_get_errors()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-get-errors.php) as follows:

```
<?php
if (($response_xml_data = file_get_contents($map_url))===false){
    echo "Error fetching XML\n";
} else {
   libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
   $data = simplexml_load_string($response_xml_data);
   if (!$data) {
       echo "Error loading XML\n";
       foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
           echo "\t", $error->message;
       }
   } else {
      print_r($data);
   }
}
?>
```

If the problem is you can't fetch the XML code maybe it's because you need to include some custom headers in your request, check how to use [stream_context_create()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php) to create a custom stream context for use when calling `file_get_contents()` on example 4 at http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: when i used the code above this give "Error loading XML\n" only not any other message

Comment: then the problem must be with `file_get_contents($map_url)`. If your URI is valid and allow_url_fopen is On it may be that you need to provide a custom context when calling the function...

Comment: that will dump a ton of gibberish and not report the errors - because you have no oid on libxml_get_errors()

Answer (score 8):

`file_get_contents()` usually has permission issues. To avoid them, use:

```
function get_xml_from_url($url){
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');

    $xmlstr = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $xmlstr;
}
```

Example:

```
$xmlstr = get_xml_from_url('http://www.camara.gov.br/SitCamaraWS/Deputados.asmx/ObterDeputados');
$xmlobj = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
$xmlobj = (array)$xmlobj;//optional
```

Answer (score 3):

`$url = 'http://www.example.com'; 
$xml = simpleXML_load_file($url,"SimpleXMLElement",LIBXML_NOCDATA);`

$url can be php file, as long as the file generate xml format data as output.

Answer (score 1):

It is working for me. I think you probably need to use `urlencode()` on each of the components of `$map_url`.