# Yahoo weather forecast - <yweather:forecast

Tags: php, yahoo, weather

I have this code

```
require('magpierss/rss_fetch.inc');
$url = 'http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?p=AUXX0013'
$rss = fetch_rss($url);
$title = $rss->items[0]['title'];
$description = $rss->items[0]['description'];
```

How to take data, for example  (code="33" ) from this part of xml

```
<yweather:forecast day="Thu" date="25 Sep 2014" low="43" high="57" text="Mostly Clear" code="33"/>
```

Comment: So, your question is how to parse XML in PHP?

Comment: I understand how to parse, but i have problem with this part

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a library that was made to parse RSS when the data that you want to extract is not part of a normal RSS document.

Just [read the XML data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12542469/416224) and then use an [xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) to get the data that you need.