# Really dirty xml output. Need to import into mysql but, any sugestions on how to clean the print view so I know what I'm working with?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, xml

```
    <?php
$map_url = "http://archive.org/download/birdbookillustra00reedrich/birdbookillustra00reedrich_files.xml";


//Get and parse XML data. This code comes from and has explinations here.
//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12542469/how-to-read-xml-file-from-url-using-php

if (($response_xml_data = file_get_contents($map_url))===false){
    echo "Error fetching XML\n";
} else {
   libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
   $data = simplexml_load_string($response_xml_data);
   if (!$data) {
       echo "Error loading XML\n";
       foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
           echo "\t", $error->message;
       }
   } else {
      print_r($data);
   }
```

This code reads the xml file then shows print_r.   BUt this code I've found

```
function xml2array ( $xmlObject, $out = array () )
{
    foreach ( (array) $xmlObject as $index => $node )
        $out[$index] = ( is_object ( $node ) ) ? xml2array ( $node ) : $node;

    return $out;
}
```

Is supposed to turn it into an array.

but I can't figure out how to merge the two. I then want to insert it into a mysql database but that is after I can figure out how to turn it into an array.

Thanks

Brandon

//// Modified to

```
<?php
$map_url = "http://archive.org/download/birdbookillustra00reedrich/birdbookillustra00reedrich_files.xml";


//Get and parse XML data. T
if (($response_xml_data = file_get_contents($map_url))===false){
    echo "Error fetching XML\n";
} else {
   libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
   $data = simplexml_load_string($response_xml_data);
   if (!$data) {
       echo "Error loading XML\n";
       foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
           echo "\t", $error->message;
       }
   } else {
      print_r($data);
      $dataarray = xml2array($data);
   }
}

for ($i = 0; $i++; $i < count($dataarray) {
   $item = $dataarray[$i];
   // Insert query here using $item.
}
?>
```

Now I get this error code.

"( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting ')' in C:\wamp\www\ebookstore\New folder\fopen2.php on line 22"

Comment: Browsers can display XML files in a pretty way with collapsible element nodes. Here are online services that can reformat the XML.

Answer (score 0):

The first part is simple. Where you currently have `print_r($data);`, also add something like `$dataarray = xml2array($data);`. That will save the xml data in `$dataarray`.

Then, loop through the array and run insert querys:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($dataarray); $i++) {
   $item = $dataarray[$i];
   // Insert query here using $item.
}
```

Since I don't know your table structure, I can't help you beyond this.

Comment: ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting ')' in C:\wamp\www\ebookstore\New folder\fopen2.php on line 22

Comment: You can see the modified code above. It's how I put it together to get that error.

Comment: @user3050153 Sorry my bad. I updated my answer; copy the edited code.