# Simplexml_load_file errors

Tags: php, xml-parsing, simplexml

I'm triying to parse this address in PHP

```
$url = 'http://pubapi.yp.com/search-api/search/devapi/search?searchloc=91203&term=pizza&format=xml&sort=distance&radius=5&listingcount=10&key=t266jc29dx' ;
$x1 = simplexml_load_file($url);
```

But here's what I keep getting

> Warning:
>   simplexml_load_file(http://pubapi.yp.com/search-api/search/devapi/search?searchloc=91203):
>   failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal
>   Server Error in...

As you can see I'm only getting part of the url parameters.

Can you help?

Comment: It gives an error because it's trying to parse the ampersand in the string. Throw your contents of the url in a variable first then process the returned XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[With some quick searching on how to retrieve XML via cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12542469/how-to-read-xml-file-from-url-using-php) this is what I did to retrieve and parse the XML.

The big reason as I mentioned above in a comment is that you can't pass URLs directly into the simple_xml_load_string function with ampersands(&) in them. It's a character in the XML format that represents entities.

```
<?php

function get_xml_from_url($url){
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');

    $xmlstr = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $xmlstr;
}

$url = 'http://pubapi.yp.com/search-api/search/devapi/search?searchloc=91203&term=pizza&format=xml&sort=distance&radius=5&listingcount=10&key=t266jc29dx';
$contents = get_xml_from_url($url);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($contents);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($xml);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```