# Loading a Remote XML Document with DOMDocument

Tags: php, xml, dom

First time with XML, but I've spent a while trying to just take any old XML document from the internet and spit out the whole thing.

```
$url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=Quentin+Road+Brooklyn%2C+New+York%2C+11234+United+States&destination=550+Madison+Avenue+New+York%2C+New+York%2C+10001+United+States&sensor=false";
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load($url);
print $xmlDoc->saveXML();
```

I've tried it with SimpleXML too, but for some reason whatever I put in as the URL there it refuses to print.

Solution:

- Use cPanel to edit php.ini:

  allow_url_fopen = On
  allow_url_include = On
- The code from the top solution here: [Simplexml_load_file errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44441404/simplexml-load-file-errors?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- Make sure you are actually printing something!

Comment: Do you have `allow_url_fopen` enabled in your php.ini.  Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/features.remote-files.php for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

- Use cPanel to edit php.ini and add:

  allow_url_fopen = On

  allow_url_include = On
- The code from the top solution here: [Simplexml_load_file errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44441404/simplexml-load-file-errors?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- Make sure you are actually printing something by specifying part of the object to print e.g. $xml->groups.